# CVCalendar compile time errors

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I m unable to build **CVCalendar** project available [here](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar). It gives so many initializer errors here is one error description Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIView'. I m using swift if any body can fixe this problem for me or give any other good swift API for calendar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944752/cvcalendar-setup/30961242#30961242

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Swift 1.2? You should use the `develop` branch,  It supports Swift 1.2.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! Now it finally works. I also rewarded the bounty to your answer.