# CVCalendar Setup

Tags: ios, swift, calendar, xcode6

I'm having trouble setting up the `CVCalendar By Mozharovsky` from github.

I've opened a new test project and added the CVCalendar folder to my project, then I added the CVCalendar CocoaPod.

I added the views the way the instructions said.

I get this error in the `override init()` function every time I try to run the project:

[image: Error]

Can you walk me through the step of the CVCalendar installation?
Where did I go wrong?

I'm using the latest version of `Xcode6` and `Swift`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From GitHub, switch to the `develop` branch and take the CVCalendar inside the Demo folder because for some reason they did not update the first CVCalendar folder.

[image]