# CVCalendar Set-up issue (segmentation fault: 11)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am receiving the `Command failed due to signal: segmentation fault: 11` error when running the CVCalendar from this Github: [link](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar). I am using Xcode 7.3 beta.

I tried three different methods and all gave me the same error:

1. I downloaded the libraries through Cocoapods and added it to an empty Xcode project.
2. I downloaded the zip file from the master view from the above Github, and ran the Demo Xcode project.
3. I downloaded the zip file from the "developer" view from the above Github, and ran the Demo Xcode project.

All three methods above gave me the segmentation fault 11 error.

To make sure that this is not a Ruby or Cocoapod problem, I downloaded the Ice cream Xcode project and Alamofire Cocoapod (from [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift) website) and confirmed that this error does not occur.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Check out my answer to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944752/cvcalendar-setup/30961242#30961242

Comment: I don't know if it's related to the newest version of CVCalendar, but try it, it might work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FSCalendar/0.9.0/ use this one instead.
this is simple and u can do customisation

Comment: if you want any kind of help on FSCalendar then please feel free

Comment: hey Wai Ha Lee it is link of source, how i can put all the source file here ?

Comment: Indrajit, does FSCalendar support a week view? I originally wanted to implement CVCalendar because it supports a week view mode. Reading the documentations on FSCalendar, it doesn't seem that week view is supported, is this true? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try to change scope to week
[calendar setScope:FSCalendarScopeWeek animated:YES];
To change back
[calendar setScope:FSCalendarScopeMonth animated:YES];

Comment: #i think you are using SWIFT ... so for you following lines gonna work

Comment: calendar.setScope(.Week, animated: true) AND 
        calendar.setScope(.Month, animated: true)